# rails database migration - multiple migrations have the version number x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Ok, I have stuffed up my migrations.  I tried to sort it by deleting duplicates, sorting the schema.rb etc but I don't think I have done it properly.

When I try to deploy to heroku, or rather heroku run rake db:migrate, I get

Multiple migrations have the version number 20130307005437

The migrate works fine on localhost but not heroku.

Unfortunately when I look for migration no 20130307005437, it's not there in my db/migrate.

How can I find it to sort the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this file might not be visible within your directory listing, I suspect that there might already be a file within your Git repository, which is what is causing this error from appearing on Heroku and not locally.

Please ensure that you've only got one migration inside that Git repo with that number.

Comment: I would recommend cloning the repository again into a separate directory and looking at it there.

Comment: In my github repository I have three migrations files which are the exact same.  but on my local files (even after git pull), I only have one...  Any ideas how to sort this?

Comment: You will need to `git rm` locally those deleted files, and then commit that change.