# Multiple Migrations whit same Version Number on Deployng Rails to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Im have this problem many times, i search much and not found any solution to solve, my problem is this:

After the run

```
git push heroku push master
```

When i run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

i get this error:

```
Multiple migrations have the version number 20130615132808
```

im search by this problem and found this:

[rails database migration - multiple migrations have the version number x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321905/rails-database-migration-multiple-migrations-have-the-version-number-x)

but when execute `git rm` appear some options i dont understand much about git so i need solve this problem, in localhost im delete the archives but the problem persists, thanks very much by the help.

Comment: What options don't you understand?  Please post the complete `git rm ...` you are executing and what is it that you are getting and not understanding.  Also how did the version number collide, did you manually rename the migration files?

Comment: hmm how i rename a migration after deploy to heroku ? and when i execute git rm appear this `usage: git rm [options] [--] <file>...

    -n, --dry-run         dry run
    -q, --quiet           do not list removed files
    --cached              only remove from the index
    -f, --force           override the up-to-date check
    -r                    allow recursive removal
    --ignore-unmatch      exit with a zero status even if nothing matched
`

Answer (score 1):

Just rename the files with duplicate timestamps (add 1 to the last digit) and then add, commit and push files. When you run `heroku run rake db:migrate` again all will be dandy.

And for the future remember to not copy and rename migrations by hand (so you don't get repeated version numbers)

Answer (score 0):

This might occur when you copy-paste multiple "rails generate" commands to generate migrations. The migrations generated may have the same time stamp. If you type them in (or copy-paste them) separately, they will have different timestamps.

When this happens, you can simply rename the migration files under db/migrate to contain different timestamps.